# Managing multiple hierarchies using Fragment Manager and DrawerLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-listfragment, drawerlayout

I have an app that is using a `DrawerLayout` and each item in the drawer will load a `Fragment`. The structure looks like:

- News -> News Story
- Photos -> Gallery -> Photo
- Events -> Event
- Directory -> User Type -> User Profile

Each top level is an item in the `Drawer`, tapping one will take you to that fragment and you can go deeper into that section by adding additional fragments on the stack, e.g. navigating from Photos to a Gallery to a photo in that gallery.

It gets confusing when I need to manage the navigation of each of these sections as individual stacks. On `iOS` I would use a `UINavigationController` for each section so that I could manage either separately. But on `Android` I am not sure how to do this. It is almost like I need to have multiple `Fragment Manager` instances. Without this, I feel  I will run into issues when:

- A user is deep into the News stack then switches to Photos, they navigate deep into that stack, but want to return to where they were in the News section. How can they return to that stack? And, navigate back up the News stack?

**This seems like a major design issue with Android, unless I am missing something. Any ideas on how to solve this?**

EDIT:

Basically I want what they showed at Google I/O:

[image]
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XpqyiBR0lJ4

Answer (score 1):

I just built an app with this design. I just kept adding fragments to the stack when the user was in 'News' or any sub category of 'News'. If the user navigated to 'Photos' I would just pop all of the fragments from stack with:

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(null,FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

and start adding to the stack again. I'm not sure if this is the 'right way' but it worked fine for me. I would just log the last fragment they were viewing in 'News' and restore it when they return to 'News' if that's the behavior you are looking for.

I managed multiple categories/sub-cats just fine using one Activity.

Comment: Yeah, but what if they were 3 levels deep into News, they go to Photos and go 2 levels deep, is there no way to return back to level 3 in News?

Comment: If that is the behavior you are looking you may want to manage a FragmentActivity for each category. IMO if I leave 'News' and then return, I would expect to hit the 'News' landing page and not the last page I viewed when I was there last.

Comment: But think about it like tabs in your browser. If you have two open, tab 1 you have navigated to different places, you switch to tab 2 to do something. But when you return to tab 1 and it is reset back to where you started? That would be super strange and make users frustrated.

Comment: I think a category tab in the drawer should represent a very specific place. If you had sub categories in the drawer you would expect to go to that sub category and not where you nav'd to from that sub category. That being said, as long as your cats/sub cats represent a specific place, your navigation is easily maintained with a single manager.

Comment: I used your solution with `android.support.design.widget.TabLayout`, and [so far] it's working perfectly.